# add "#" in begining to selected lines in File

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, grep

Requirement : ADD someting (i.e #) in begining of every line in file A which is grep from file B

File A

```
abcd
abdc
sdfg
asdfa
jon
ram
```

File B

```
jon
abcd
```

grep file B from file A and add "#" character in begining of the file in file A

out put shoude be

```
#abcd
abdc
sdfg
asdfa
#jon
ram
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$0 in a{printf "#";}1'  fileB fileA
```

Explanation:

`NR==FNR{a[$0];next}`  => awk reads the fileB into an array.

`$0 in a{printf "#";}` => If any line of fileA matches with any of the array content, put a # in the beginning.

`1` => Print every line of fileA

Using sed:

```
$ x=$(sed -e :a -e 'N;s/\n/\\|/;ta' FileB)
$ sed "s/$x/#&/" FileA
```

The 1st sed command prepares a string where all lines are joined together as a string and are delimited by a "|" and stored in $x. The 2nd sed inserts a # in the beginning for a line matching with any of the patterns stored in variable $x.

Comment: Thaks Very much ... i am trying to find out with "SED".....

Comment: added the sed solution..

Comment: Thank again ..... could you pls. explain the awk  logic ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the following oneliner:

```
sed "$(for str in $(cat fileB); do echo -n "s/$str/#\0/; "; done;)" fileA
```

The `sed` command is constructed in a subshell by looping over the fileB. This then used to replace the matching lines with a `#` and the matched line.